# SQLite Database Versioning and Xamarin Config String

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-sqlite, visual-studio-2017

I have an Xamarin Android (and maybe someday iOS) app that utilizes a rather sizable SQLite database (20MB+). I am somewhat new to mobile app development and definitely to Xamarin. I need to control database versioning. This is a best-practice question.

Edit/Clarification: Some of the data is app/user created or maintained. Some of the data is generated via a 3rd party and is read only, in 2nd and 3rd normal form. That data must be updated with version release. Also, the user will purchase some of these data sets in-app.

My Plan:
Everytime the app opens - OnStart (), I will validate the version of the database that is supposed to exist via a configuration string against a table value in the SQLite database with version info. If the versions don't match, the database file will be copied from the APK/assets to a local folder on the device, overwriting the existing file. I definitely don't want this to happen everytime the app opens for many reasons.

3-part question:
First, is this solution a solid approach without major road blocks? Where in Xamarin (or Android project) is best to store the database version string? And finally, is there a 3rd party library (preferably nuget) which already handles database versioning? I cannot find anything like that for .NET / Xamarin. Only some Java libraries which are more Android specific.